# How to use CoffieeScript in Appcelerator Titanium instead of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to write my code in CoffieeScript, and then convert it into JavaScript. How do I do that in Appcelerator Titanium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create your .coffee files in the Resources dir of your project, run `coffee -w -c *.coffee` and import the compiled .js files in the app.js file using `Ti.include`:

```
Ti.include('main.js');
```

A more extensive guide:
http://rigelgroupllc.com/wp/blog/building-iphone-apps-with-titanium-and-coffeescript

An useful plugin for Titanium mobile:
http://suchfuncoding.com/174/titanium_coffee_script/